# How can i configure local by flywheel v5.0.7 site.config.hbs file for roots bedrock

Tags: wordpress, local, nginx-config, roots-sage, roots-toolkit

I am a windows 10 user

i have installed local by flywheel v5.0.7 & i want to configure ***roots bedrock*** into the app folder. now how can i change the default configure (nginx > site.conf.hbs) **public folder** to ***bedrock/web folder***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oWyi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found this article which outlines using the full path to the location of the install.

> Local 5 and newer utilizes a native stack, so paths such as /app won’t work anymore. You will need to provide the entire path.

https://localwp.com/community/t/adding-bedrock-to-local-version-5/15542/3

Comment: [This](https://roots.io/docs/bedrock/master/installation/#getting-started) also helped me... these specific instructions to adjust db name, user, password etc... in addition to adjusting the relative path

Comment: For those who may wonder what to add in the .env DB_NAME, DB_USER and DB_PASSWORD it is: 'local', 'root', 'root'